# Alguien sabe cómo puedo actualizar la interfaz de usuario cuando abren mi app móvil desde una notificación enviada desde firebase. RNative y Expo go

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, firebase-messaging

Estoy usando React Native y Expo go, además de react-native-firebase/messaging, ya recibe notificaciones y todo, esa parte ya esta implementada, solo que quiero que al ser abierta mi app desde la notificación, le redireccione a una interfaz específica ( en mi caso tendría que cambiar el state), pero la documentación justamente recomienda no hacer eso.

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
}); // este código dónde debería ir? en el useeffect?
```